# JSON Decode Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Tags: php, json

I have state list in JSON format and i am using json_decode function but when i am trying to access array values getting error.

```
$states='{
    "AL": "Alabama",
    "AK": "Alaska",
    "AS": "American Samoa",
    "AZ": "Arizona",
    "AR": "Arkansas"

}';

$stateList = json_decode($states);
echo $stateList['AL'];
```

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array on line 65

Comment: You are getting a generic object back. http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see, the json_decode() method doesn’t return our JSON as a PHP array; it uses a stdClass
object to represent our data. Let’s instead access our object key as an object attribute.

```
echo $stateList->AL;
```

If you provide true as the second parameter to the function we will receive our PHP array exactly
as expected.

```
$stateList = json_decode($states,true);
echo $stateList['AL'];
```

Answer (score 3):

Either you pass `true` to `json_decode` like Nanhe said:

```
$stateList = json_decode($states, true);
```

or change the way you access it:

```
echo $stateList->{'AL'};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass true as the second parameter to json_encode or explicitly convert the class to array. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $stateList = json_decode($states);
 //statelist is a object so you can not access it as array
 echo $stateList->AL;
```

If you want to get an array as a result after decode :

```
  $stateList = json_decode($states, true);
 //statelist is an array so you can not access it as array
 echo $stateList['AL'];
```